# How to move window in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a window called 'Codes' in window 1, and I want to move it to window 7, is it possible?

Comment: What are you talking about - do you mean move a x-window to a different virtual desktop? What X windows manager are you using?

Comment: nope, I mean the window in GNU Screen. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Go to window 1, type the command character (e.g. `CTRL-A`) and then type: `:number 7`.  If there is already a window at 7, then the two windows will be swapped (window 7 will become window 1).  From the manpage:

```
   Change the current windows number. If the given  number  n  is  already
   used  by  another  window,  both  windows exchange their numbers. If no
   argument is specified, the current window number (and title) is shown.
```

Comment: @Arcege , Thanks for this answer. Following your answer I figured out from screen's manual that it is possible to provide the target window number with relative values. For example: `:number +1` would swap current window with the one just right to it. I find this option useful with key binding that controls the current window location (where one does not know the absolute index of the windows to swap).